# NullPointerException when running Crystal reports with SP24 for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, crystal-reports-2016

We are trying to upgrade to SP24 of Crystal Report for Eclipse but have found that several of our reports are failing with a NullPointerException when generating the report. I've included the stack trace below - does anyone have any idea what may be wrong or have any workarounds, please?

```
Changing Main Report Table Connection Info
Changing Sub Report Table Connection Info
Setting Parameters of Main Reports
Starting Verify database
Completed Verify database
Setting Parameters of Sub Reports
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: java.lang.NullPointerException---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.if(SourceFile:238)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:148)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:129)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:112)
    at us.nm.state.hsd.aspen.business.batch.rp.crystal.RpJRCExportReport.runReportExport(RpJRCExportReport.java:742)
    at us.nm.state.hsd.aspen.business.batch.rp.crystal.RpScheduleReportRun.process(RpScheduleReportRun.java:177)
    at us.nm.state.hsd.aspen.business.batch.rp.crystal.RpScheduleReportRun.drive(RpScheduleReportRun.java:263)
    at us.nm.state.hsd.aspen.business.batch.rp.crystal.RpScheduleReportRun.main(RpScheduleReportRun.java:286)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.d.a(SourceFile:154)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.ObjectFormatter.a(SourceFile:332)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.ObjectFormatter.a(SourceFile:250)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.u.a(SourceFile:922)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.u.e(SourceFile:784)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.f.e(SourceFile:383)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.u.for(SourceFile:242)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.aa.a(SourceFile:64)
...
```

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs I got -  The webpage cannot be found error.

Comment: [did you try this?](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1201380)

Comment: I faced the same problem while I was running with java-8-openjdk, and I switched to jdk-1.8.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else is running into the same problem here.

Problem is: Newer JDK versions are not shipped with a lib/fonts folder which the Crystal Report engine expects.

A somewhat unsatisfying, but working solution is:

1. Create a fonts folder -> %JAVA_HOME%/lib/fonts
2. Copy fonts from 'Windows\Fonts' into %JAVA_HOME%/lib/fonts.

Problem should be solved then.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue, copying the jre/lib/fonts folder from Java8 to Java 11
-jdk/lib/fonts solved the issue.