# com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed

Tags: java, crystal-reports, sap

trying to open rt file using crystal reports and getting below "null pointer exception",
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed

I tried with 12 version of crystal report and jdk 8 and jdk 11.
Can some help me understanding this issue?

Comment: Check out the question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663452/nullpointerexception-when-running-crystal-reports-with-sp24-for-eclipse) and see if it might be applicable to your issue.